# React JS get json data and print in text field with perticular selected ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

This react code I am writing for accepting the data from `test.php`

```
  var BasicInputBox = React.createClass ({
                    render: function (){
            //getting the input field to display the details
                      return (
                       <div>
                        <tr><td>
                          <label>{this.props.label}</label></td>
                           <td><input type="text" onChange = {this.props.valChange} value = {this.props.value}/></td>
                        </tr>
                       </div>
                      );
                    }
                });
                var DataInTableFormat = React.createClass({
                    getInitialState: function() {
                      return {
                        phpData : [],//initialize the data and the id
                        id : ''
                      };
                    },
                    componentDidMount: function() {
                      var url = document.URL;  
                      var currentId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 4);//getting the current ID of the student to and send it to the test.php through AJAX.
                      var data = {
                      idtoUpdate: currentId
                      };
                      $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'test.php',
                        data: data
                        })//post the ID through AJAX to test.php this will works fine.
                        .done(function(data) {

                        })
                        .fail(function(jqXhr) {
                        console.log('failed to register');
                        });
//getting the data returned from the test.php
                      $.get(this.props.source, function(result) { ////storing the JSON data in result
                          var collection = JSON.parse(result); // //coverting JSON data to Javascript object
                          if (this.isMounted()) {//checking for component mount.
                            this.setState({
                              phpData: collection //collecting the all JSON data
                           });
                          }
                        }.bind(this));
                      },
                    fetchData : function(){
                      console.log("onClick fetch")
                    },
                    nameChange: function(event){
                         this.setState({name: event.target.value})
                    },
                    render : function(){ 
                      DBdata = this.state.phpData || [];
                      return(
                        <div>
                              <table>
                                {DBdata.map(function(d){
                                 return(
                                    <BasicInputBox label="Student Name :" valChange={this.nameChange} value={d.name}/>
                                    )}
                                 )}
                                    <tr><td><td><button name="fetch" value="fetch" onClick={this.fetchData}>fetch</button></td></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><td><button name="submit" value="submit">update</button></td></td></tr>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                          )
                      }
                   });
                  React.render(
                    <DataInTableFormat source="http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/test.php" />,
                      document.getElementById('Table-data')
                    );
```

When I am changing the path to the index.php(which prints the all data in a JSON form it works nice. And when test.php(which returns the single student information then I am getting the error

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: idtoUpdate in D:\wamp\www\PHP-React-Demo\test.php on line 6

Comment: i could be wrong but it could be that your php returns an HTML page as a response rather than a JSON string. try doing `console.log(result);` before doing `JSON.parse()` and check the `console` panel of your browser for the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the JSON data in a text field in React JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306128/print-the-json-data-in-a-text-field-in-react-js)