# Print the JSON data in a text field in React JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

this code I am writing after componentDidMount :

```
componentDidMount: function() {
                  var url = document.URL;  
                  var currentId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 4);//getting the current ID from the url
                  var data = {
                  idtoUpdate: currentId
                  };
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: data,
                   success: function(response) {
                    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $("#briefinfo").html(response);//This response will prints the JSON format data which is return by test.php

                   }
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {

                    })
                    .fail(function(jqXhr) {
                    console.log('failed to register');
                    });
                },
```

Here I am getting the JSON format code When I return the response it prints 
so I want to print this data in a textfield

Comment: I'd recommend storing the response in state and in render method write the state value as the value of an input/textarea tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code...

```
var someComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
      return {"response":null};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      var url = document.URL;  
      var currentId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 4);//getting the current ID from the url
      var data = {
        idtoUpdate: currentId
      };
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: data,
       success: function(response) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(response);
        this.setState({"response": response});
       }.bind(this)
      })
      .done(function(data) {

      })
      .fail(function(jqXhr) {
        console.log('failed to register');
      });
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <textarea value={this.state.response} readonly={true}/>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this not what you want? Please elaborate your question with an example of how/what the text area should display?

Comment: The text area displays only name of particular id not a JSON data

Comment: Per my original request, please provide the example of the right data which should be visible in the textarea vs what is visible using the sample code I provided. Also, do remove any private data from your code unless you are comfortable sharing it publicly.

Comment: This is returning on textarea {"id":"4238","name":"Muddasar","email":"muddasar@nadsoftdev.com","phone":"99855‌​46142","marks":"70"}]

Comment: But I need the only name field i.e Muddasar only

Comment: Then change the textarea code to this -
`<textarea value={JSON.parse(this.state.response).name} readonly={true}/>`
On a separate note, please read more about React and JSON. This is a very trivial issue.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Now this is heading towards hand-holding... Let me leave this as an exercise for you to figure out.